# Why is the brightness often lowered in scenes showing lightning?

Tags: anime-production

First time I've noticed this was in FMA Brotherhood (image contains anime spoiler) :

> [image]

I thought it was just for this show but apparently every other anime I've watched follow the same "rule", BNHA :

[image]